# Betta fish ignores bloodworms as food

Tags: behavior, fish, feeding, betta, live-food

I recently purchased bloodworms as a supplemental food for my Betta fish, which are often represented as a "treat" for them. However, even though my Betta fish swims to the front of the tank for food when he sees me, he often simply ignores bloodworms. I'm slightly confused why, since he eats pellets and flakes promptly. What would cause this? Does he not like them, are they too big for him, or does he simply not realize that they're food?

I already tried tearing them into smaller pieces hoping that it would help him eat them more easily. Is there something else I could try, or should I just accept that he won't eat them?